# Distribution of a random variable exercise

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading section 1.1 of Terence Tao's [book](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf) on random matrices, which is a review of probability theory, and I couldn't prove the following exercise, which I copied almost verbatim here:

> **Independence.** When studying the behaviour of a single
> random variable X, the distribution of X captures all the probabilistic
> information one wants to know about X. The following exercise is
> one way of making this statement rigorous: 
> **Exercise 1.1.10.** Let $X$, $X'$ be random variables (on sample spaces $\Omega, \Omega'$ respectively) taking values in a measurable space R (e.g. the real numbers equipped with Borel sigma-algebra), such that they have the same distribution.
> Show that after extending the spaces $\Omega, \Omega'$, the two random variables are isomorphic, in the sense that there exists a probability
> space isomorphism $\phi: \Omega \to \Omega'$ (i.e. an invertible extension map
> whose inverse is also an extension map) such that $X = X' \circ \phi$.

By "extending" and "extension map" Tao means the following:
we say that one probability space $(\Omega', \mathcal{B'}, P')$ extends another probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, P)$ if there is a surjective map $\pi: \Omega' \to \Omega$ which is measurable and probability preserving (i.e. $P'(\pi^{-1}(E)) = P(E)$ for every $E \in \mathcal{B}$). Every event $E$ in the original probability space
is canonically identified with an event $\pi^{-1}(E)$ of the same probability in the extension. We also think of a random variable X on the original sample space as the "same" as the random variable $X \circ \pi$ on the extended sample space. This identification enables us to add in new random variables that are independent of the existing events and random variables.

So far, I know that WLOG, I can assume that $\Omega$ equals $\Omega'$ by extending them to the product space $\Omega \times \Omega'$. Then I am stuck.

Comment: Can you provide a link to his notes?

Comment: What does "taking values in a range $R$" mean? Does it mean their image is $R$ for both, so $X(\Omega) = X'(\Omega')=R$?  If not, what happens, for example if we have $X:\Omega\rightarrow [0,1]$ and $X':\Omega\rightarrow [0,1]$, $X$ is uniform over $[0,1]$ and $X(\Omega)=[0,1]$, but $X'=X1_{\{X\neq 1/2\}}$? Then $X'$ cannot take the value $1/2$, but $X$ and $X'$ have the same distribution.

Comment: @Galen link added!

Comment: @Michael I think Tao just means R is an arbitrary measurable space, and it does not have to be the image of the two random variables, even though he uses the word range.

Answer (score 1):

As in my comment above, this looks impossible unless we assume $R$ is the image set:
$$ R = X(\Omega) = X'(\Omega')$$
So let us assume this. Here are some thoughts in that direction...

---

**Incomplete idea:** What if we define
\begin{align}
S &= \{(w,z) : w\in \Omega, z \in \Omega', X(w)=X'(z)\}
\end{align}
Since $X$ and $X'$ have the same image, for each $w \in \Omega$ there is a $(w,z) \in S$, and for each $z \in \Omega'$ there is a $(w,z) \in S$. Then define extended spaces:
$(\Omega_e, B_e, P_e)$ and $(\Omega'_e, B'_e, P'_e)$ by
$$ S = \Omega_e = \Omega'_e$$
with $B_e$ and $B'_e$ appropriately defined sigma algebras. Then define $\pi(w,z)=(w,z)$ as the identity function on $S$.  Then the extended random variables are
\begin{align}
X_e(w,z) &=X(w)\\
X'_e(w,z) &=X'(z)
\end{align}
and if we fix $(w,z) \in S$ we get
$$X_e'(\pi(w,z)) = X_e'(w,z) = X'(z)=X(w)=X_e(w,z)$$
where we have used the fact that $(w,z)\in S \implies X(w)=X'(z)$.

Now this answer has absolutely nothing to do with the fact that $X$ and $X'$ have the same distribution, it only uses that they have the same image.

**Problem:** In comments below I gave the sigma algebras I was initially considering for $B_e$ and $B_e'$.  As Justt points out, the answer above lacks the measurability property for  $\pi$. The identity function can only be measurable if $B_e=B_e'$. Now I wonder if another (single) sigma algebra $F=B_e=B_e'$ can be formed on $S$ with the property that for any $A \in F$, the projection of $A$ onto $\Omega$ is a set in $B$ and the projection of $A$ onto $\Omega'$ is a set in $B'$. Perhaps take a sigma algebra generated by sets of the type $A_1 \times A_2 \subseteq S$ with $A_1 \in B$ and $A_2 \in B'$. I'm not sure if this will work...[Rough draft proof, likely buggy: Let $C$ be the collection of all subsets $A\subseteq S$ with the property that the projection of $A$ onto $\Omega$ is in $B$ and the projection of $A$ onto $\Omega'$ is in $B'$. We want to show $C$ is itself a sigma algebra on $S$. Now $S$ is in $C$.  Also I believe countable unions of sets in $C$ is also in $C$, perhaps even complements...?]

**Higher level question:** Even if this exercise can be solved, it is not clear to me how it relates to Tao's statement "**the distribution of X captures all the probabilistic information one wants to know about X. The following exercise is one way of making this statement rigorous.**" That statement seems to relate more to the idea that if $P[X\leq x]$ is known for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then that uniquely fixes $P[X \in B]$ for all Borel subsets $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sounds fishy: what probability measure do you put on $S$?

Comment: Given $A \in B_e$ we define $P_e[A] = P[\{w \in \Omega : (w,z) \in A\}]$. Simiarly $A \in B_e'$ we define $P_e'[A] = P[\{z \in \Omega' : (w,z) \in A\}]$. So the hard part is defining $B_e$ and $B_e'$. I believe this will work as a sigma algebra on $S$: Define $B_e$ as the collection of all sets $A \subseteq S$ such that $\{w : (w,z) \in A\} \in \Omega$ and $\{z : (w,z) \in A\}$ is the set of all $z$ such that $X'(z) = X(w)$ for some $w \in \{w : (w,z) \in A\}$.

Comment: Yes that might work on $\Omega_e, B_e$ and $\Omega_{e'}, B_{e'}$ separately, but you also need (as per the question) an isomorphism of measured spaces between $\Omega_e$ and $\Omega_{e'}$. Obviously you want to take the identity, but in that case you want $B_e = B_{e'}$ and $P_e = P_{e'}$, and either of these can fail.

Comment: @justt : Thanks for the scrutiny.  There may be something weird as I think this is a weird question (overall, requiring $X(\Omega)=X'(\Omega')$ seems needed).   I was not assuming  $B_e=B_e'$. Perhaps there are some measurability assumptions or "extension map" assumptions I am not fulfilling in my attempt above.

Comment: I think the statement of the exercise is just a blunder on Tao's part tbh. In my answer I put what I believe to be the correct statement, which is consistent with the context of the exercise. You could solve the exercise if $\Omega, \Omega'$ and $R$ were Radon spaces, using disintegration of measure, but this cannot be what he meant...

Comment: I asked the question on Tao's blog, we will see if he comments. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/254a-notes-2-the-central-limit-theorem/comment-page-1/#comment-643761

Comment: Tao responded and agreed the question needed fixing, he created a new erratum statement as follows (also see his blog): Page 18: Exercise 1.1.10 is incorrect as stated.  Replace the second sentence with “Show that there exists a random variable Y (on the sample space R) taking values in R, such that X is equal almost surely to an extension of Y (to the sample space \Omega), and X' is equal almost surely to an extension of Y (to the sample space \Omega').

Comment: However I do not think this is true.

Comment: It is true, and is almost a tautology. Y is the identity $R\to R$, $X$ is the extension map $\Omega\to R$, and $X'$ is the extension map $\Omega'\to R$.

Comment: Oh, subjectivity is not guaranteed... I see that now. I'm not sure how to make it surjective by modifying it on an event of measure zero. OTOH, I'm not sure the surjectivity assumption is very useful to the point Tao wants to make...

Comment: It may be true by exploiting "almost surely" with respect to the probability space on $\Omega$ and then separately (with different prob measure) with respect to the prob space on $\Omega'$ (not almost surely with respect to the $R$ space).  One difficulty is pinning down the exact statement we are trying to prove when the statement is in pieces. But I feel embarrassed that I wrote on Tao's blog my followup objection then I notice that maybe my counter-example can be avoided by taking the "almost surely" on different parts of the two different spaces.

Comment: @justt : If you can solve the exercise please ping me to let me know.

Comment: @justt : But what if the cardinality of $R$ is larger than the cardinality of $\Omega$? How can there be a surjective function from $\Omega$ to $R$ that enables an extension of $Y$?

Comment: @Michael yeah I also think it is impossible when the cardinality of R is larger than the cardinality of Ω. I think the statement will be correct if we do not put assumptions on the domain of Y. Then we can let Y be the identity map on $I = X[\Omega] \cap X'[\Omega']$ and let the extension map be X restricted to $X^{-1}[I]$ so that this extension map is indeed surjective and yet equals X almost surely. After all, I think what Tao wants to emphasize is the "X is equal almost surely to an extension of Y, and X' is equal almost surely to an extension of Y" part, not what Y looks like.

Comment: @Michael: you are right. This surjectivity assumption is problematic and should be dropped. For all probabilistic intents and purposes, an extension is "almost surjective", in that the measure of the range is $1$.

Comment: (and sorry for having misled you into thinking you weren't)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to show that if $X: \Omega \to R$ is and $X' \Omega \to R$ are measurable, then there exists two measurable spaces $\widetilde \Omega$, $\widetilde \Omega'$ and four measure preserving surjective maps $\pi : \widetilde \Omega \to \Omega$, $\pi' : \widetilde \Omega' \to \Omega'$,  $\widetilde \pi  : \widetilde \Omega \to \widetilde \Omega'$ $\widetilde \pi^{-1} :  \widetilde \Omega \to \widetilde \Omega'$ such that $\widetilde \pi^{-1} \circ \widetilde \pi = Id_{\widetilde \Omega}$ and $$X \circ \pi = X' \circ \pi' \circ \widetilde \pi.$$

But, as Michael said, if $X$ is surjective and $X'$ is not (which does not prevent them to have the same distribution, see his comment), then the latter equality states that a surjective random variable is equal to a non-surjective one, which is impossible.

I think that the exercise is stated the wrong way around and that the correct statement could be that $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ are extensions of the same probability space (namely $R$, trivially, the extension maps being $X$ and $X'$ themselves).

Edit : Tao fixed the exercise, the updated statement is exactly what I suggested above.

Edit 2 : as pointed out by OP and Michael Neely, the fixed exercise works only if you forget about the "surjectivity" assumption of the extension maps. This is indeed a silly assumption if you ask me, because otherwise the two good points Tao makes, namely

> Probabilistic statements are statements that are stable under extension maps

and

> the distribution of X captures all the probabilistic information one wants to know about X

can't be simultaneously true.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments of Michael's and Justt's answers, the statement of the exercise needs to be modified. If the statement is "show that there exists a random variable Y such that X is equal almost surely to an extension of Y (to a subset of the sample space \Omega), and X' is equal almost surely to an extension of Y (to a subset of the sample space \Omega')", then I can summarize the comments into a proof as follows:

Let $I = X[\Omega] \cap X'[\Omega']$. As a subset of $R$, equip it with the sigma-algebra inherited from R. Equip $I$ with the measure $P_I$ defined by $P_I(E) = P(X \in E) = P'(X' \in E)$. Note that $X$ restricted to $X^{-1}[I]$ is then an extension map, and so is $X'$ restricted to its preimage of $I$ (in particular, they are surjective). Denote $X$ restricted to $X^{-1}[I]$ as $\pi$ and the restricted $X'$ as $\pi'$.

Let $Y$ be the identity map on $I$. Then $Y \circ \pi$, an extension of $Y$, is simply $X$ restricted to $X^{-1}[I]$. $X^{-1}[I]$ is almost all of $\Omega$ by the fact that $X$ and $X'$ are equal in distribution:
$$P(X^{-1}[I]) = P(X \in X'[\Omega']) = P'(X' \in X'[\Omega']) = 1,$$
so $Y \circ \pi$ equals $X$ almost surely. Similarly for $Y \circ \pi'$.

Comment: Brilliant, so the easiest thing to drop in Tao's erratum was the requirement to have $Y$ defined on the sample space $\Omega$.

Comment: You should accept your own answer!

Comment: What happens if (Ω)∩′(Ω′) is the empty set? Also, (Ω) and ′(Ω′) are not required to be measurable sets (so expressions of the form $P[X \in X'(\Omega')]$ do not necessarily make sense).  It is possible to have random variables :Ω→[0,1] and ′:Ω′→[0,1] (i.e., Borel measurable functions) that are both uniformly distributed over [0,1] but (Ω) and ′(Ω′) are nonmeasurable disjoint subsets of [0,1].

Comment: @Michael yeah that is a big problem. I want to say that $X[\Omega]$ and $X'[\Omega']$ are almost equal, but I cannot even take the measure of $X[\Omega] \Delta X'[\Omega']$. I tried to replace the sigma algebra of R by its completion and argue that $X[\Omega] \Delta X'[\Omega']$ is a subset of a null set, but I cannot even find such a null set. So yeah, I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: @Michael I am curious about an example of uniformly distributed X, X' whose images are   nonmeasurable disjoint.

Comment: @HankY : On such weird examples, I have some recent notes I made on this (which is why I was interested in your question to begin with).  The example I have in mind is involved and I will try to type it up and make it available in some form, I'm not sure if such examples exist elsewhere.  It uses a nonmeasurable set $A \subseteq [0,1]$ such that neither $A$ nor $A^c$ contain a Borel subset of positive measure. I will define $X:A\rightarrow [0,1]$ and $X':A^c\rightarrow [0,1]$ by the identity functions $X(w)=w$, $X'(w)=w$. The trick is defining the sigma algebras and probability measures.

Comment: @Michael thank you! It can be a very crude sketch if it is involved. I don't want to take up  your time.

Comment: @HankY : I had typed up the notes I mentioned, on uniform random variables with disjoint images, but now I see almost exactly the same thing on this arxiv here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7148